# I can't get to work the IF statement

Tags: javascript

```
    </script>   
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var p1 = 94.28
    var p2 = 86.43 
    var p3 = 85.36
    var p4 = 82.26
    var p5 = 80.03 
    var p6 = 77.60
    var p7 = 72.75

    function calculate11() {
    var USERINPUT11 = document.TESTING11.INPUT11.value,
                RESULT11 = (( p1 * USERINPUT11) / 1000 ); 


            document.TESTING11.OUTPUT11.value = RESULT11;
            }

                 if( USERINPUT11 => 3000 ); {
             {RESULT11 = (( p2 * USERINPUT11) / 1000 ); ; 
        }
        //This IF statement is not working. 

</script>
```

I can't get to work the if statement, the user will input a value, and depending of the value it will calculate differently.  any help would be appreciate and thank you.

Comment: Remove the semi-colon on this line: `if( USERINPUT11 => 3000 );` Also, I'm not sure in JavaScript, but it may be `>=` instead of `=>`.

Comment: [`=>` (fat arrow)](https://strongloop.com/strongblog/an-introduction-to-javascript-es6-arrow-functions/) `>=` (more or equal)

Comment: is the if statement suppsed to be inside the `calculate11` function?

Answer (score 1):

Three things that I see..

1. Remove the semicolon after the condition.
2. Fix the comparator.
3. Put the if statement inside the function. (Clean up your curly braces)

Doing that you get..

```
function calculate11() {
    var USERINPUT11 = document.TESTING11.INPUT11.value,
        RESULT11 = (( p1 * USERINPUT11) / 1000 ); 

    document.TESTING11.OUTPUT11.value = RESULT11;

    if( USERINPUT11 >= 3000 ) {
        RESULT11 = ((p2 * USERINPUT11) / 1000 );
    }
}
```

Now I'm going to assume you want to call the if statement before you use the object affected inside it. That will look something like this...

```
function calculate11() {
    var USERINPUT11 = document.TESTING11.INPUT11.value,
        RESULT11 = (( p1 * USERINPUT11) / 1000 ); 

    if( USERINPUT11 >= 3000 ) {
        RESULT11 = ((p2 * USERINPUT11) / 1000 );
    }

    document.TESTING11.OUTPUT11.value = RESULT11;     
}
```

Now since it is pretty clear you are just doing a conditional assignment, how about we use the [ternary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) operator and refactor just a little to make it pretty.

```
function calculate11() {
    var USERINPUT11 = document.TESTING11.INPUT11.value;

    var pFactor = USERINPUT11 < 3000 ? p1 : p2;

    document.TESTING11.OUTPUT11.value = (pFactor * USERINPUT11) / 1000;     
}
```

Voila! Hope that helps and maybe try a [javascript tutorial](https://www.codecademy.com/learn/learn-javascript) to learn more.